# Is there an easier way to check for values in a registry path then delete all values im looking for?

Tags: powershell

So Im running power shell script where it tests the path of a registry value and if it exists it will be deleted. Question if there are more values within the registry key whats a simpler way of detecting and deleting them all? I dont want to repeat the same script for every single value.

```
$registrypath=("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings" , "DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays" )
if (Test-Path $registrypath)
{
  cmd /c reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings /v DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays /f
}
```

Comment: so is just deleting the whole key if some condition exists an option?

Comment: Just the value, there are more values under the settings key that i want to delete otheriwse i need to recopy that code above and replace the value from deferfeatureupdatesperiod.. with another key to remove it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-itemproperty?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

To remove all Properties and their values from a registry key , without removing Sub Keys and the key itself You just need to run :
`Remove-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name *`